# How to use Font Dialog with .NET 6 Desktop Application using WPF?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, .net-6.0, desktop-application

I surfed a lot on MSDN and other forums to find `FontDialog` in .NET 6 using WPF. But unfortunately, I could not find any references.

I am developing a Desktop using .NET 6 and it does not allow to include `FontDialog` form `System.Windows.Forms` assembly. I tried finding any available Nuget Packages from Microsoft but failed to get any.

I would appreciate if someone help me to get some good technical references or guidance.

Comment: Hsve you set `<UseWindowsForms>true</UseWindowsForms>` in .csproj file?